"error: Unexpected null value for column" while it does contain a value
I created an SQLite database using fmdb and inserted data. I am now using sqlite.swift instead of fmdb. It crashes when I read a key of type blob which does have a value:

SQLite/Query.swift:1235: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Unexpected null value for column

The code:
func fetchAllNotes() -> [Note] {
    guard let db = db else {
    print("Database connection is not available.")
    return []
    }

    var notesArray = [Note]()

    do {
    for note in try db.prepare(notes) {
    let note = Note(
        id: note[id],
        title: note[title],
        content: note[content],
        isdraft: note[isdraft],
        fontsize: note[fontsize]
    )
    notesArray.append(note)
        }
    } catch {
    print("Failed to fetch notes: \(error)")
    }

    return notesArray
}


struct Note: Identifiable {
    let id: Int64
    let title: String
    let content: Blob
    let isdraft: Int
    let fontsize: Int

    init(id: Int64 = 0, title: String, content: Blob, isdraft: Int = 1, fontsize: Int = 16) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.content = content
    self.isdraft = isdraft
    self.fontsize = fontsize
    }
}

_swift_runtime_on_report:
libswiftCore.dylib`:
->  0x7ff8156f7320 <+0>: pushq  %rbp //Crashed in this line
    0x7ff8156f7321 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x7ff8156f7324 <+4>: popq   %rbp
    0x7ff8156f7325 <+5>: retq
    0x7ff8156f7326 <+6>: nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)

swift_unexpectedError:
0x7ff81546c3fa <+826>: pushq  $0x0
0x7ff81546c3fc <+828>: pushq  -0x68(%rbp)
0x7ff81546c3ff <+831>: pushq  %rax
0x7ff81546c400 <+832>: pushq  -0x70(%rbp)
0x7ff81546c403 <+835>: callq  0x7ff815414870            ; Swift._assertionFailure(_: Swift.StaticString, _: Swift.String, file: Swift.StaticString, line: Swift.UInt, flags: Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never
->  0x7ff81546c408 <+840>: nopl   (%rax,%rax)


What is the Blob type in Swift?

I tried to covert to type Data, it still doesn't work, same issue.

https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/a95fc6df17d108bd99210db5e8a9bac90fe984b8/Sources/SQLite/Core/Blob.swift#L25 Since you can do Blob <-> [UInt8] and Data -> [UInt8] you can use Blob... Is it what you've done? But the stacktrace of the crash might help a lot...

@Larme Thank you, and yes, I have done like this. The stacktrace
libswiftCore.dylib`:
->  0x7ff8156f7320 <+0>: pushq  %rbp // This line error
    0x7ff8156f7321 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x7ff8156f7324 <+4>: popq   %rbp
    0x7ff8156f7325 <+5>: retq   
    0x7ff8156f7326 <+6>: nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)

